# Java serialization extension of class

Tags: java, android

suppose i have a class `Article`

```
public class Article implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1420672609912364060L;
   private String title;
   private String text;
   private UUID uid;

   public Article(){ //empty default constructor
   }

   // Getters and setters 
   ...  
}
```

and I serialize multiple instances of it using the following code

```
public void save(Article article)
{
    FileOutputStream fos = null;
    try {
        fos = context.openFileOutput("article_"+ article.getUid(), Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        ObjectOutputStream os = new ObjectOutputStream(fos);
        os.writeObject(article);
        os.close();
        fos.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I then later extend the class making it look like this:

```
public class Article implements Serializable
{
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1420672609912364060L;
   private String title;
   private String text;
   private Person author;
   private UUID uid;

   public Article(){
       author = Person.UNKNOWN;
   }

   // Getters and setters 
   ...
}
```

Then when I load it in, why is author null? I always thought the default constructor was called and then the setter for every found property, but putting a breakpoint in the default constructor and then debugging shows it isn't called. Meaning that for the old Article class, the author would simply be null instead of Person.UNKNOWN. The class `Person` itself is also serializable.

This is my loading in code if it might be relevant.

```
private Article loadArticle(String fileName)
{
    FileInputStream fis = null;
    try {
        fis = context.openFileInput(fileName);
        ObjectInputStream is = new ObjectInputStream(fis);
        Article article = (Article ) is.readObject();
        is.close();
        fis.close();
        return article;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InvalidClassException e) {
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that is all Android configuration

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I always thought the default constructor was called

Nope it wasn't. Take a look at the [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html)

> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is serializable. **The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored from the stream.**

Comment: Then how can I extend my class while keeping it serializable? (nescessary for passing it as an object betweeen android activities)

Comment: You should not - that's whole idea of `Serializable` objects that you can be sure they won't change. Moreover changing class definition without changing `serialUID` is basically mistake. If you want to provide feature like this simply provide your own way to serialize/deserialize (using e.g. gson/jackson) and provide mechanisms to 'migrate' older instances to the new definition

Comment: Thanks. I now save them using Google's GSON library and this works exactly like I want it.

Comment: Great, I'm glad to help you ;)

Answer (score 0):

No, the default constructor is not called - it just sets every field, that has not been found in the serialized data, to 0.

You can manually set custom fields on deserialisation like that:

```
public class Article implements Serializable {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1420672609912364060L;
   private String title;
   private String text;
   private transient Person author;
   private UUID uid;

   public Article(){
       author = Person.UNKNOWN;
   }

   /**
    * Called upon deserialisation
    */
   private void readObject(ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
       // read non transient fields
       in.defaultReadObject();
       author = Person.UNKNOWN;
   }

   // Getters and setters 
   ...
}
```